# is there any difference in these two class implementation?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner of programming and dart lang. I have a question about how to write class about database service related to flutter and firestore.

```
// what is the difference this
class DbService {
  final Firestore _db;
  DbService() : _db = Firestore.instance;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getDataCollection(String id) {
    return _db.collection(id).getDocuments();
  }
}
// and this
class DbService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getDataCollection(String id) {
    return _db.collection(id).getDocuments();
  }
}


   // when use this class
_dbService = DbService();
```

What is the best practice. or should I use singleton to instantiate this class? Any comments or help is appreciate.

Comment: is the same, you could go with the first one in case you need to pass a parameter in your constructor but in this case you are not passing any parameters so it's the same

Comment: There's no difference between both whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same for computer, but they give me different impression.

2nd one is obvious, where 1st one telling me the constructor used to take value, or may be take value in future version.

Comment: Thanks so much for answer. I understand it now!